# Comparing categorical variable results across multiple time points

Tags: time-series, categorical-data

I'd like to compare categorical variable results across multiple time points. In the example below, group 3 has a drop in positives from 14 to 4. As I understand it, contingency table tests such as the Fishers exact test or Chi-squared test are not appropriate because 100% of all samples have been tested at each time point. ANOVA is not appropriate either as I am not comparing means. What would be the most appropriate statistical test?  Thank you

[image]

Comment: The Groups are what constitute the categories of the nominal feature?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question? Each group in this example represents a category (group 1=weak positive, group 2=medium strength positive; group 3=strong positive)

Comment: Well, if you want to treat the three categories as ordered 1<2<3 consider using Friedman rank test. If the three categories are nominal (like cat dog rabbit) consider using Fleiss kappa.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Reading about both tests makes me think that they may not be the most suited for this. What I am trying to ask is whether the decrease for group 3 at day 10 is significant in relation to group 1 and 2. Another issue is that the total number of participants tested at day 10 is less than at day 1 due to loss to follow-up. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Thanks @ttnphns for the suggestions above. I’ve now used both Cohen’s Kappa and Fleish’s Kappa in R (irr package) and both give me a moderate Kappa (moderate strength of agreement between 2 raters (1 rater = day 1; 2nd rater = day 28 result)) with a significant p value. These results confirm that there are differences between day 1 and day 10 results if they were taken by 2 different raters/observers. But what I am looking for is a test that allows me to say or refute that group 3’s decrease is more substantial than the changes seen in the other groups. Any advice?

Comment: Reading further, I've found that the fleiss kappa is to be "used when participants are rated by different sets of raters. This means that the raters responsible for rating one subject are not assumed to be the same as those responsible for rating another (Fleiss et al., 2003)." This means that this is unsuitable for my question and dataset unfortunately. In my situation, the same test is being applied to a biological sample at different time points with results changing due to changes in the disease itself.

Comment: Please return to my first comment. It appears now that Group is not your response variable. Rather, there is a response variable with values "positive" and "negative". Right? And Group is a factor variable, three independent, constant subsets of the sample of individuals. Right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct (I was incorrect earlier).

Comment: A possible solution? How about a chi-squared contingency comparison between results on day 1 VS day 10 (a 4x4 contingency table, which includes negatives). This gives a significant p value suggesting a relationship between results on day 1 and 10 (not independent), which allows me to state that the drop seen in group 2 is real. If my reasoning is wrong – would be grateful for correction!

Comment: The analysis you want is not an elementary one. You have between-subject factor Group and within-subject (repeated measurement) factor Day, and the response attribute is binary (pos/neg). The most appropriate analysis is via GEE (generalized estimating equations) with logit link function. Your focus if interest wull be the signifinance of the interaction effect between the two factors.

Comment: A simpler (yet less rigorous) approach could be to compute the response variable showing the change between day 1 and day 10, with the three values, hence, 1, 0 and -1. This variable can be compared between the groups by Mann-Whitney or Kruskal-Wallis tests.

Comment: Thank you very much @ttnphns. You have helped me a great deal!